# Parsing and splitting a string from txt file in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, parsing, split

I'm new into C and I got an assignment to read line by line from .txt file and parse some strings into matrix where first line is first row, second line is second row etc. This is what I have in my text.txt file:

```
07 45 C4 16 0F 02 19 0I 17 0G 
09 45 C4 15 0E 03 11 0A 12 0B 13 0C
13 45 C4 13 0C 03 19 0I 11 0A 17 0G 14 0D 16 0F
05 45 C4 18 0H 01 12 0B
```

This is what I was able to do so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *Read(char filename[]);

void split(char *content);

int main(void){

    char filename[] = "text.txt";
    char *content = Read(filename);
    split(content);
    return 0;
}

char *Read(char filename[]){

    char *buffer;
    long size;

    FILE *log = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    fseek(log, 0, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(log);
    rewind(log);

    buffer = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
    fread(buffer, 1, size, log);
    fclose(log);

    return buffer;
}

void split(char *content){

    char *buffer = strtok(content, " ");
    while(buffer != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", buffer);
        buffer = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate comments in code because I'm rookie and it would help me to better understand some things.

Comment: What are the factors that determine when you should split the characters?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "when". It should be parsed line-by-line and each line should be split in format I explained before.

Comment: you are just reading the file and printing it? Where are you splitting it?

Comment: Read, put into array and print. If you mean where in my code I do the splitting, that's the problem. I don't know how and where to do splitting. I only know how to open file and read it line-by-line.

Comment: @Mihajlo Please be more clear as to how you want to split the string. Is it like if it begins with a 0 it is two character long and if it begins with 1 it is 4 characters long?

Comment: It's doesn't matter how it begins. It's only important that first 2 (07, 09, 13, 05) characters represents one block, second two (45) are second block, third two (C4) are third block,  then fourth block contains 4 characters (160F, 150E, 130C, 180H), fifth contains two again (02, 03, 03, 01), sixth contains 4 characters (190I, 110A, 190I, 120B), seventh too (170G, 120B, 110A) and so on... I edited original post with additional two strings so I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: If an answer solved your problem or helped you, please consider to accept it, see also:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

To give you an idea of how it works, I wrote this snippet which manually read the line in that array, supposing that we already know the desired results.

The following approach cannot be considered the right one. Ideally you would have a series of rules to split the string, in the following however you have to set the scanf format manually for each line that you want to read.

Remember to check the return value of scanf, here we should ensure that we have read 7 elements.

```
int main(void) {
    FILE *log;
    char buffer[SIZE];
    char line[SIZE];

    char array[10][10];

    if ((log = fopen("text.txt", "r")) == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't open input file!\n");
        return(1);
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), log)){
        int ret = sscanf(buffer, "%2s%2s%2s%4s%2s%4s%4s", array[0], array[1], array[2], array[3], array[4],array[5], array[6]);
        printf("read %d elements\n", ret);
        if (ret != 7) {
           return(1);
        }
        printf("%s", buffer);
    }

    int i;
    for (i=0; i < 6; i++)
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);

    fclose(log);

    return 0;
}
```